# The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

So i am trying to create an S3 bucket but if i apply the replication settings, i get the follow error

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400

If i comment out the replication settings, the bucket gets created perfectly. I am unable to debug the issue , any help will be welcomed, Following is my S3 bucket.

```
Resources:
  PipelineS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub ${Env}-${BucketName}
      AccessControl: BucketOwnerFullControl
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: !Ref SSEAlgorithm
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload:
              DaysAfterInitiation: !Ref DaysAfterInitiation
            ExpirationInDays: !Ref LifecycleConfigurationExpirationInDays
            NoncurrentVersionExpirationInDays: !Ref NoncurrentVersionExpirationInDays
            NoncurrentVersionTransition:
              StorageClass: !Ref LifecycleConfigurationStorageClass
              TransitionInDays: !Ref TransitionInDays
            Prefix: !Ref LifecycleConfigurationPrefix
            Status: !Ref LifecycleConfigurationStatus
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: !Ref VersioningConfigurationStatus

      ReplicationConfiguration:
        Role: !GetAtt BucketBackupRole.Arn
        Rules:
          - Destination:
              Bucket: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket'
              StorageClass: Standard
            Prefix: ''
            Status: Enabled
            Id: Region2Rep
  BucketBackupRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - s3.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "configureable-bucket-policy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - s3:*
                Effect: Allow
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket'
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `StorageClass` try using all caps `ENABLED`

Based of [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-replicationconfiguration-rules-destination.html#cfn-s3-bucket-replicationconfiguration-rules-destination-storageclass) in the cloudformation docs

```
ReplicationConfiguration:
  Role: !GetAtt BucketBackupRole.Arn
  Rules:
    - Destination:
        Bucket: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket'
        StorageClass: Standard
      Prefix: ''
      Status: ENABLED
      Id: Region2Rep
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LifecycleTransition properties Days and Storage Class.

```
var _s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKeyId, _awsSecretAccessKey, _bucketRegion);
LifecycleConfiguration newConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration
    {
        Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
        {
            new LifecycleRule
                    {
                         Id = "some id here",
                         Filter = new LifecycleFilter()
                         {
                             LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecyclePrefixPredicate()
                             {
                                
                             }
                         },
                         Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
                         Transitions = new List<LifecycleTransition>
                         {
                              new LifecycleTransition
                              {
                                   Days = 0,
                                   StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Glacier
                              }
                          },
                         Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration()
                         {
                               Days = 1
                         }
                    }
        }
    };
PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest putRequest = new PutLifecycleConfigurationRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Configuration = newConfiguration
            };
 _s3Client.PutLifecycleConfiguration(putRequest);
```